# Atribuição de boolean dentro de um operador ternário

Tags: python

Eu gostaria de saber por que essa sintaxe é inválida e como fazer o equivalente com um operador ternário

```py
seventh_state = False

state_machine_var = 1

for x in range(0, 10):
  state_machine_var += 1
  (seventh_state = False, seventh_state = True)[state_machine_var == 7]
```

A quinta linha é considerada como uma sintaxe inválida, mas eu usei o template

```py
(if_test_is_false, if_test_is_true)[test]
```

e isso funciona.

Mudar isso para um `if` normal também resolve o problema

Comment: Estamos no [pt.so], então, por favor, faça sua pergunta no nosso idioma. Aproveite para fazer o [tour], ler o guia de [ask] e acessar a [help].

Comment: O que quer fazer? Este código não faz sentido. Aproveita e traduz para o português.

Comment: Você quer que `seventh_state` seja `False` quando `state_machine_var` for diferente de 7 e `True` quando for igual, então por que não faz apenas `seventh_state = (state_machine_var == 7)`? Muito mais simples, mais fácil de ler e entender e tem sintaxe válida.

Comment: Este código é uma simplificação do código original, é normal não fazer grande sentido fora de contexto. Agradeço a resposta @AndersonCarlosWoss ! Mas não responde à minha pergunta

Comment: Aliás, na linha anterior, `loop x in range(0, 10)`, esse `loop` não existe no Python, talvez o erro de sintaxe comece aí. Possivelmente seria `for` o correto, adicionando os dois pontos ao final da linha.

Comment: Já corrigi @AndersonCarlosWoss mas o erro foi ao passar para aqui, o loop está correto

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR:** O operador ternário em Python é escrito da forma:

```
resultado_pro_caso_verdadeito if condicao else resultado_pro_caso_falso
```

Com as palavras chave `if...else` separando os 3 termos.

---

Em Python,  as coisas são diferentes de linguagem que herdam a sintaxe diretametne do C, como Java, Javascript entre outras.

Primeiro, até o Python 3.7 (a versão mais atual), ações de atribuição são exclusivamente comandos (statments), e não podem ser usadas como parte de uma exprssão. (A partir do Python 3.8 isso será possível com o uso do operador `:=`)

Além disso, o operador ternário que existe nas linguagens parecidas com C: `expr? res_true: res_false` item uma sintaxe diferente em Python - ele usa um `if...else` em linha como em `res_true if expr else res_false`.

Então a sua expressão

```
(seventh_state = False, seventh_state = True)[state_machine_var == 7]
```

deve ser escrita, se fosse necessária, como:

```
seventh_state = True if state_machine_var == 7 else False
```

Só que nesse caso você não precisa nem disso - já que a própria expressão `state_machine_var == 7` já tem resultado booleano `True` ou `False`, então você só precisa mesmo de:

```
seventh_state = state_machinne_var == 7
```

## Histórico e outras formas

A sintaxe para operadores ternários `expr1 if condition else expr2` só foi implementeda na versão 2.5 do Python, que é de 2006. Antes disso as pessoas recorriam a receitas do tipo da que está na pergunta para tentar ter a mesma funcionalidade. A recomendação oficial, no entanto, era criar um conjunto de `if/else` com blocos separados mesmo.

**A primeira receita** para operadores ternários no Python antigo, que ainda pode ser encontrada em muitos tutoriais e livros de Python 2 tirava proveito de uma característica dos operadores `and` e `or` do Python - e sugeria usar a seguinte forma: `cond and expr1 or expr2`

A ideia dessa forma é a seguinte:

- Uma expressão com `and` só tem valor "True" se seus dois operandos são positivos. Então a linguagem faz um atalho: se tiver `expr3 and expr4` e `expr3` for falsa, o código de `expr4` nunca é executado. Além do atalho, há uma característica - o valor todo de `expr3 and expr4` se expr3 é verdadeiro, é `expr4` - o `and` não testa o expr4 -  não importa se o valor dela é um objeto "verdadeiro" ou "falso", como ela só foi executada respeitando o  `and` o seu valor é o valor final do `and`.
- Já o `or` é o contrário - o atalho da linguagem é: se em  `expr5 or expr6`, `expr5` tiver um valor verdadeiro, o seu resultado é usado como valor da expressão toda e `expr6` nunca é executada.
- A precedência do `and` é maior que a precedência do `or`, então `cond and expr1 or expr2` é o mesmo que `(cond and expr1) or expr2`
- assim sendo, em `cond and expr1 or expr2` o operador `and` sempre vai executar a `expr1` somente se a expressão dada em `cond` for verdadeira. E então vai ter como resultado, em vez de "True/False" o resultado da `expr1`. O operador `or`, por sua vez, se esse primeiro operando dele for verdadeiro, ele assume o valor daquele operando e  se for falso, o segundo operando - `expr2` é avaliado e usado como resultado da expressão toda.

O grande problema dessa forma é que se o valor de  `expr1` tiver um valor booleano falso em Python, a expr2 vai ser usada de qualquer forma - mesmo que a condição seja verdadeira. E em Python, os objetos None, qualquer número com valor 0 (int, float, complex, Fraction, Decimal ou outro tipo de número personalizado), qualquer sequência, mapa ou container vazio ("", [] set(), {}) são objetos com valor booleano falso.

**A segunda receira** é como a que aparece na pergunta aqui: cria-se uma sequência com as expressões de resultado desejadas, e usa-se a condição como índice dessa sequência - se valendo do fato de que em Python, os booleanos True e False também tem valores numéricos 1 e 0, respectivamente:
`[expr2, expr1][cond]`

Tem duas desvantagens: uma que a ordem das expressões desejadas é invertida  - ou seja, quando cond for True, o Python pega o valor no índice 1 da sequência, que é o segundo. A outra é que não importa a condição, as `expr2` e `expr1` sempre são executadas - se envolverem uma chamada de função que use recursos, fica ruim, ou pior, ou fizerem contas com valores que não estão disponíveis se `cond` for falsa, nem é possível escrever a expressão dessa forma.

## Futuro

A partir do Python 3.8 (atualmente em Beta, release previsto para o final de outubro de 2019), as atribuições em expressões com o operador `:=` passarão a valer, e isso aumenta muito a utilidade do operador ternário - já que é possível re-utilizar um valor calculado durante a condição.

Assim, se é necessária uma chamada de função "cara" e depois executar código dependendo do resultado dessa chamada, mas usando o valor de retorno, até hoje (Python 3.7), a única forma de fazer isso é:

```py
valor_intermediario = funcao_cara()

if valor_intermediario > 5:
    resultado = coeficiente_grande * valor_intermediario
else:
    resultado = coeficiente_pequeno * valor intermediaio
```

Com o novo tipo de atribuição essa sequência passa a  poder ser escrita assim:

```
resultado = coeficiente_grande * interm if (interm:= funcao_cara()) > 5 else coeficiente_pequeno * interm
```

Comment: A título de curiosidade, já vi algumas publicações dizendo sobre fazer `(if_test_is_false, if_test_is_true)[test]`, ou melhor, `result = (if_test_is_false, if_test_is_true)[test]`, que no contexto da pergunta ficaria `seventh_state = (False, True)[state_machinne_var == 7]`; mas de qualquer forma é injustificável fazer isso.

Comment: Essa forma de usar o boolean como um índice para uma tupla era uma forma usada, as vezes, antes da sintaxe de operadores ternários - que salvo engano é do Python 2.5 . Os dois grande problema dessa forma são, primeori todas as expressões são executadas - não só a expressão "escolhida" e segundo que fica uma construção um pouco estranha, que leva algum tempo para quem está lendo entender as reais intenções (inclusive por que os valores de para "True" e "False" ficam invertidos -a expressão para o caso verdadeiro tem que estar em segundo lugar, no índice 1)

Answer (score 2):

O erro de sintaxe que você cita é devido ao fato de estar fazendo atribuições dentro da inicialização de uma tupla. Isso não é possível, não até a versão 3.7, como o jsbueno já comentou em sua resposta.

Para entender melhor, vamos analisar o *template* utilizado:

```
(if_test_is_false, if_test_is_true)[test]
```

Existem duas expressões, `if_test_is_false` e `if_test_is_true` que são avaliadas pelo interpretador, independente do valor de `test`, para construir uma tupla com os resultados. Os únicos índices possíveis dessa tupla serão 0 ou 1, e dada a implementação do Python, é permitido que seja acessível através de valores booleanos, visto que `False` é equivalente ao valor `int(0)` e `True` ao valor `int(1)`, o que justifica as posições dos valores na tupla, sendo o primeiro a expressão para quando o teste falhar e o segundo para quando for bem sucedido.

A atribuição, como fez, não é uma expressão válida para inicializar uma tupla tal como fez:

```
(seventh_state = False, seventh_state = True)[state_machine_var == 7]
```

Basta analisar qual seria a tupla a ser construída nesse contexto. Você até poderia alterar para

```
seventh_state = (False, True)[state_machine_var == 7]
```

Que passa a possuir uma sintaxe válida e produz o resultado esperado, porém não existem justificativas para se fazer isso. Prejudica a legibilidade do seu código, cria um *overhead* desnecessário tanto para se definir a tupla quanto para as operações de acesso nela. Resumidamente, esta expressão só tem pontos negativos quando comparada à expressão com o operador ternário:

```
seventh_state = True if state_machine_var == 7 else False
```

E, ainda essa expressão é redundante, pois você explicitamente está dizendo que uma variável deve ser `True` quando a condição é `True` ou `False` caso contrário. Então por que não já atribuir o resultado da condição?

```
seventh_state = (state_machine_var == 7)
```

Seu código fica muito mais simples e legível.